# Is it illegal for a leasing agent to share previous tenants direct debit form?

Tags: privacy, rental-property, australia, banking

I am a tenant of a residential property in Victoria Australia. I requested my rental ledger and direct debit form to apply for a new property.

My rental agent has (accidentally???) sent me the direct debit form for another tenant's property, which includes the full names of tenants, address, bank details, service agreement and signature for this property.

Was this illegal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Maybe

If the agent is one covered by the Australian Privacy Act then this would appear to be a breach of [APP6](https://www.oaic.gov.au/privacy/australian-privacy-principles-guidelines/chapter-6-app-6-use-or-disclosure-of-personal-information/) - Use or disclosure of personal information. The agent would be [covered](https://www.oaic.gov.au/privacy/your-privacy-rights/tenancy/#WhatIsResidentialTenacyDatabase) by the act if they have an annual turnover of more than $3 million or they operate (not just access) a Residential Tenancy Database.

If they are not covered by the Act, there is no breach of the law.